# Using ETL for AWS Glue on Lambda instead of EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a workflow where I require the use of ETL function to be able to read a json file (stored in S3) in AWS Athena, however, as the JSON file contains nested arrays, Athena refuses to continue with the query. I know we can use Zeppelin on an EC2 machine to run ETL but I do not wish to run an EC2 machine, was wondering if its possible to use Lambda instead? Has anyone tried this before ?

The nested json that I am using:

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "generated": "Wed, 1 May 2021 02:11:23",
  "site": [
    {
      "name": "Alaska",
      "host": "example.com",
      "port": "443",
      "ssl": "true",
      "details": [
        {
          "name": "alaska",
          "record": "0000100",
          "type": "example",
          "count": 11
          "description": [
            {
              "meta": "meta",
              "method": "GET",
              "key": "abc"
            },
           ]
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Eg of a query that I would need: How can I query all the type and its count ?

This is the error when I try to query

Your query has the following error(s):
HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH: There is a mismatch between the table and partition schemas. The types are incompatible and cannot be coerced. The column 'site' in table 'sampledb.codebuildprojectname' is declared as type array<struct<...

Comment: What do you mean with "Athena refuses to continue with the query"? I have nested JSON nested array and it works fine, can you share more details?

Comment: Hi @Hyruma92, thanks for your reply, I have edited the post with a nested JSON nested array, please let me know how I can query in Athena, thank you in advance !

Comment: I don't know how you defined the table, but the error is pretty clear: the schema definition is not matching the data. As first step (since you mentioned AWS Glue) I'll suggest to use a AWS Glue Crawler to inspect the data. This will create the table definition in your catalog based on the data, so you will resolve the schema mismatch. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html

Comment: I did use AWS Glue to create the table, however, the schema only consist of the higher level objects like version, generated and site. When I try to query the site, the error above will show up, any thing that I can improve on ?

Comment: Try to add more details as possible, schema definition and query example

Comment: @jrchew Can you do https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-hive-partition-schema-mismatch/ and confirm if that fix this issue?